# How to use OpenMP in a makefile?

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, g++, openmp

I'm using a Makefile for setting up the environment needed for mo code. I'm just learning about parallelizing and would appreciate your help.

```
# The list of packages used by the macro:
USED_PKGS = xAODRootAccess xAODTruth xAODJet xAODMissingET
test: test.o
    `root-config --ld` -o $@ `root-config --libs` \
        -L$(ROOTCOREDIR)/lib `rc get_ldflags $(USED_PKGS)` $^
clean:
    rm -f test.o
    rm -f test
.SUFFIXES: .C .o
.C.o:
    `root-config --cxx` -c -o $@ `root-config --cflags` \
        -I$(ROOTCOREDIR)/include `rc get_cxxflags $(USED_PKGS)` $<
```

I have installed OpenMPI and have added it to PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

My code is very simple and just want to check it against the Makefile:

```
int main()
{
    int i;
#pragma omp parallel for
    for ( i = 0; i < 1e8; i++ )
    {
        int y = 2*i;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is completely unclear what you are asking. SO is not a site for inidivualized tutorials, so if you have a problem, please state it clearly, otherwise search for a beginners tutorial on the web.

Comment: @Vroomfondel I want to use parallelization for the above code. But, instead of using g++ test.C -fopenmp I want to use the Makefile that I have for compiling it. Does it make it clear? Thanks.

Comment: You need to rework your question. Currently your whole posting is missing a single question mark except in the title ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, So I figured it out myself after playing around. In case anyone else is looking for the same thing the Makefile should look like:

```
# The list of packages used by the macro:
USED_PKGS = xAODRootAccess xAODTruth xAODJet xAODMissingET
test: test.o
    `root-config --ld` -o $@ `root-config --libs` \
        -L$(ROOTCOREDIR)/lib `rc get_ldflags $(USED_PKGS)` $^ -fopenmp
clean:
    rm -f test.o
    rm -f test
.SUFFIXES: .C .o
.C.o:
    `root-config --cxx` -c -o $@ `root-config --cflags` \
        -I$(ROOTCOREDIR)/include `rc get_cxxflags $(USED_PKGS)` $< -fopenmp
```

-fopenmp should be added to both lines.

Comment: Do you really need `-L$(ROOTCOREDIR)/lib` and `-I$(ROOTCOREDIR)/include`?
These should be provided by `root-config --libs` and `root-config --cflags`.

Comment: I honestly don't know. I got this Makefile from another person :)